# Mixing Azure AD and Azure AD B2C Authentication within same reactjs app and aspnet core web api

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

How do we mix Azure AD and Azure AD B2C in same app? I am building an app which should be accessible to employees and customers. My requirement is to authenticate internal users(like employees) with Azure AD and external users(customers) with Azure AD B2C.

What do I know so far.
I can build two web apis(with just differing Startup.cs), the same can be done at reactjs as well - This is not ideal

Code in index.js of react app

```
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { MsalProvider } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { msalConfig } from './config';
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Fragment>
    <StrictMode>
      <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
        </Provider>
      </MsalProvider>
    </StrictMode>
  </Fragment>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Current Code in `Startup.cs` os aspnet core api

```
// 'AzureAd' and 'AzureAdB2C' is configured in appsettings.json
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(_configuration, "AzureAd");
// + services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(_configuration, "AzureAdB2C"); <---- Would this work?
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, PermissionPolicyProvider>();
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionAuthorizationHandler>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Federate Azure AD to Azure AD B2C.
Users can then click a button on AAD B2C login page to login with their AAD account. Your app just needs to understand AAD B2C as a login provider. Much simpler.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: This seems to be great. I just read MSAL can do this without AD changes or policies. See this statement "MSAL is a unified library that helps you to develop applications that work with Microsoft Accounts, Azure AD accounts and Azure AD B2C users indifferently – all in a single, streamlined programming model!". I don't see any samples which do the same though. Link - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/security-compliance-and-identity/microsoft-identity-at-build-2016/ba-p/249712

Comment: All application sample for AAD B2C use MSAL already. MSAL sends the user to AAD or AAD B2C, one or the other. Send the user to AAD for Work/School/Microsoft accounts. Use MSAL to send the user for AAD B2C for Consumer/Federated accounts. MSAL can only be pointed to AAD **OR** AAD B2C.

Comment: Now it is clear. The documentation stating "treating users indifferently" made me think I can add both providers and MSAL make the determination based on email domain names.